# List the history of text field while typing on the field in an Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

In my eclipse RCP application i have a text filed to get some values from the user.
Is there any way in eclipse RCP or java to list the old entries while entering the new values [Like content assist]?
Please advice me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.AutoCompleteField` for this. For a text field it might look like this:

```
   new AutoCompleteField(text, new TextContentAdapter(), new String [] {"proposal 1", ...});
```